# Bootstrap toggle the nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using the following code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">NavBar</a>

    <button 
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Blue</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Red</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Green</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    
</nav>
```

When the window is small enough the nav bar li stuffs disappear and the menu icon appear, that is good. But when the menu icon appear and I click on it, li stuffs do not appear as it suppose to be. The nav li stuffs should appear below each other.

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add the boostrap script tag at the begining of your code:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is the version for bootstrap@5.2.3, but You just have to find the one for bootstrap@5.0.2

With this your nav bar work fine !

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-light">

<a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">NavBar</a>

<button 
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
    class="navbar-toggler"
    aria-controls="navbarNav"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Blue</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Red</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Green</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>


</nav>
```

Comment: The problem was, I forgot to add the boostrap script tag